# how to compare and sort figures in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

so I read article about sorting element in arrays. Here is some code in:

```
 function compareNumeric(a, b) {
   if (a > b) return -1;
   if (a < b) return 1;
 }

 var arr = [ 1, 2, 15 ];

arr.sort(compareNumeric);

 alert(arr);  // 1, 2, 15
```

I do not undetstand logic of it. Why we dont use for() in this case?

Comment: Why would you use `for`? That would require you to implement a sorting algorithm on your own which would be incredibly slow compared to a good one that's implemented in C or C++ (in the JS engine itself).

Comment: What Thief said, also your function can be simplified by just doing `return b - a;`

Comment: I do not understand it as I said. I think that we can compare each element in array with each other by for(). That what is what I think

Comment: There are many sorting algorithms which you can implement using some variation of `for`. The point of `.sort` is that it has already implemented these, all you need to supply is your custom comparison logic. I invite you to implement a sorting algorithm using `for` and then let us know if it's preferable to using `.sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.sort() function allow a callback function to compare the array items. Your callback function is called multiple times from the sort algorithm.
this link might help you http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

check this link out...
n yaa you are using sort function only..so no need of for loop.
and in js when you use sort function for numerical i/p, you have to give function as an argument to tell how to sort....

---

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to sort the array.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var points = [40,100,1,5,25,10];
points.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=points;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

try this function it is simpler...